# Apply "where" expression to generic dbset to filter certain data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I am writing a system that has something similar to roles; a user can only see data that they have rights to. This applies to data used for form population, searches, lists, reports, etc.

The way I planned on implementing this adding a filter to Get requests by adding a "WHERE" clause to the EF query just before execution.

This would be simple were it not for the fact that we are using generics.

The Get function used to be this

```
public class EntityFactory<TEntity, TDto> : IEntityFactory<TEntity, TDto> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DBContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private DbSet<TEntity> _dbset;

    public EntityFactory(DBContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        //...
    }

    public async Task<List<TDto>> GetAsync()
    {
        List<TEntity> d = await _dbset.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        return _mapper.Map<List<TDto>>(d);
    }
}
```

And what I would like to do:

```
public async Task<List<TDto>> GetAsync()
{
    //If the object implements a special interface
    if (i.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IFoo)))
    {
        //expression to filter the data on a linked table containing the user's Id.
        Expression<Func<Bar, bool>> exp = x => x.Foos.Any(a => a.UserId == _user.UserId);

        //add the expression to the dbSet
        _dbSet = _dbSet.Where(exp);
    }

    //Execute the get
    List<TEntity> d = await q.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

    //return the converted objects
    return _mapper.Map<List<TDto>>(d);
}
```

But this does not work! I get this compiler error:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Bar, bool>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity, int, bool>>'
```

Is there a way to either:

- create a "dynamic" query that is not checked or
- change the dbset to the required type, apply the expression and return it to the generic type?

Comment: `Queryable.Where` already works with generics and expressions. Why are you creating a different expression? And why are you replacing the *field* instead of creating a new query? How can you even *do it* without a compilation error? `Where` returns an IQueryable. Also check what the error says - it talks about an `Expression<System.Func<TEntity, int, bool>>`. Have you created your own `Where` perhaps? You don't need to

Comment: Have you created extension methods that shadow LINQ's own methods perhaps? Why? There are some very strange comments in the code too - `//If the object implements a special interface
    if (i.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IFoo)))
` What object and why not a generic constraint? Why is the object a field instead of a parameter? Did you put the data access code in the entity itself, or implement it as a base class for entities? This is the exact opposite of using an ORM

Comment: I am still a noob when it comes to generics and I am working on code that was written by another developer. I will have to see if he created extra extension methods.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The Where is not a custom extension, it is from System.Linq. However, there are 2 where functions, one is the "expected" <TSource, bool> the other is the <TSource, int, bool> one. Is there a reason why it would call the wrong method?

Comment: LINQ to EF doesn't have two `Where`. LINQ to Objects does. DbSet *doesn't* have a `Where` nor can you assign an IEnumerable or IQueryable to a DbSet field. Somehow, somewhere in your code you've mixed up field names and types.

Comment: Perhaps you should remove all that code and start with a simple query? The code you posted has multiple compilation errors. Stormcloak's answer shows that adding a condition to a query is trivial. Get that working before thinking how to make this "automatic" for all entities. You may not want to in the end - you could write a simple function `IQueryabel<T> ForUser<T>(IQueryable<T>, string)` that takes an existing query and returns a new one after appending a `Where(it=>it.UserID=_user.ID)`

Comment: Also check Jimmy Bogard's article on [Filters](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/29/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-filters/) and the related [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Filters/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq dynamic query to apply where clause.

```
var query = _dbSet.AsQueryable();
//If the object implements a special interface
if (typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
{
    query = query.Where("UserId = @0", _userId);
}
List<TEntity> d = await query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I get an error "'Where' does not take 2 arguments.". Changing the argument to string the compiler complains that string is not a valid argument

Comment: You should add "System.Linq.Dynamic" namespace.

Comment: There's no need to use string filters. `Where` works just fine with expressions. The original error suggests the problem isn't Where. In fact, how can the result of `Where` be assigned to a DbSet field?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, yes, you are right. But already the dynamic query is performing it for us.

Comment: @Stormcloak because you *haven't* mixed up EF and enumerables. If you had, it would probably throw at runtime and you wouldn't even notice. Besides, it's yet another dependency. This answer shows the correct way to make the query though - make a *query* and add conditions to it, not the DbSet

Comment: The dynamic is interesting and I have it working to a degree, but part of my problem is that the UserId is in a different table that is linked to the table that the query is being execute against. How do I access that field?

Answer (score 0):

You may be better served by finding a different way of looking at this problem.  Since this is a security filter, you could find that unexpectedly a IFoo wasn't implemented and you aren't filtering when you thought you were.

That being said, you can do this but it requires a couple of steps.  You could build the expression manually, but I prefer to build the expression in code and then use a ReplaceVisitor to modify the expression for the current type.

First I create a filtering expression of type `Expression<Func<IFoo,bool>>`.  This isn't the final filtering expression but it is compatible since we are checking to see that the generic type implements IFoo.

Next I use an Expression Visitor to replace each reference to the IFoo parameter expression with a TEntity parameter expression.  The resulting expression will be an `Expresssion<Func<TEntity,bool>>`, so I cast it to that so the compiler will be happy.

Finally, I pass the resulting expression to the Where clause.

Note: This is a non-async version, but it demonstrates the principles.

```
public class EntityFactory<TEntity, TDto> : IEntityFactory<TEntity, TDto> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(v => { }));
    private DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
    private Type i = typeof(TEntity);

    private Expression<Func<IFoo, bool>> getFilterExpression(int userId)
    {
        return (x => x.Foos.Any(a => a.UserId == userId));
    }

    private class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly Expression _originalExpression;
        readonly Expression _replacementExpression;

        public ReplaceVisitor(Expression originalExpression, Expression replacementExpression)
        {
            _originalExpression = originalExpression;
            _replacementExpression = replacementExpression;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            return _originalExpression == node ? _replacementExpression : base.Visit(node);
        }

        public static Expression VisitExpression(Expression node, Expression originalExpression, Expression replacementExpression)
        {
            return new ReplaceVisitor(originalExpression, replacementExpression).Visit(node);
        }
    }

    public List<TDto> Get()
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;

        //If the object implements a special interface
        if (i.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IFoo)))
        {
            var userId = 7;

            var baseFilterExpression = getFilterExpression(userId);
            var filterExpression = (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)ReplaceVisitor.VisitExpression(
                baseFilterExpression,
                baseFilterExpression.Parameters.First(),
                Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity)));

            //add the expression to the dbSet
            query = query.Where(filterExpression);
        }

        List<TEntity> d = query.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        return _mapper.Map<List<TDto>>(d);
    }
}
public interface IEntityFactory<TEntity, TDTO> { }
public interface IFoo
{
    List<FooItem> Foos { get; set; }
}
public class FooItem
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```